# How to Best Implement nearest neighbour search in mysql?

Tags: mysql

So, in short,

1. What should be the data type of latitude and longitude?
2. What SQL command I should call to get the first 100 nearest restaurants for example?

Detail:

I have 100k biz record each with lattitude and longitude. I see that MySQL actually support a data type called point. Should I use that instead?

Does MySQL support KDTree storage system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KDTree-animation.gif

Is it best to use point data type rather than regular float data type to store latitutude and longitude?

Eventually I want to find things like the first 100 restaurants closest to points 105,6 for example and my databases contains a lot of biz and points. Obviously computing the distance one by one for every records and for every points would be O(n) and hence sucks.

Notice that I am aware of a simpler solution described in [How do Application Like Yelp Retrieve distance information from data base efficiently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4210/how-do-application-like-yelp-retrieve-distance-information-from-data-base-efficie) and will implement that my self too for a start. That's a good answer.

However, I think there is one creme of the crop answer that should outperform that right? In fact, storing location based on latitude and longitude and finding stuffs nearest to it is a very common problem I expect mysql to have a special design pattern for that. Does it have that?

Where can I learn more about it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720773/sql-efficient-nearest-neighbour-query)?

Comment: It looks like the solution in here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4210/how-do-application-like-yelp-retrieve-distance-information-from-data-base-efficie is the best solution. I mean there is this thing called MYSQL spatial. However you can't pull out things like where (distance (x)<20). It's not implemented yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as design patterns, the [Yelp question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4210/how-do-application-like-yelp-retrieve-distance-information-from-data-base-efficie) is pretty standard stuff.

For a more complex answer, you will probably need the geospatial distance. [Here](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/2/Geo%20Distance%20Search%20with%20MySQL%20Presentation.ppt) is a fascinating powerpoint about that topic (and [here](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf) is a pdf version of that as well).  However, the math involved is quite ugly.

From their slide:

```
set @orig_lat=122.4058; set @orig_lon=37.7907;
set @dist=10;

SELECT *, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(
POWER(SIN((@orig_lat - abs(dest.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) +  COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.lat) * pi()/180) *  POWER(SIN((@orig_lon – dest.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as  distance
FROM hotels dest 
having distance < @dist
ORDER BY distance limit 10
```

There's a longer, more in-depth answer about geospatial distance on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096385/formulas-to-calculate-geo-proximity).

But you still want to limit the results by latitude and longitude.

Ultimately, I would avoid the POINT datatype and go with latitude/longitude.  There's currently no way to determine the distance between two POINTs, so you're going to have to store latitude/longitude for that calculation anyways.

One last link:  you may also want to check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902287/get-polygons-close-to-a-lat-long-in-mysql) regarding speeding up the queries using spatial indexes.

Comment: [ERROR in query 4] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '– dest.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as  distance
FROM network_pos dest
having d' at line 2

Comment: Hi, the @dist is on milles? thank

Comment: @OlafErlandsen yes it's in mile

Answer (score 4):

Point datatypes are OK; you can just invoke X(coord)/Y(coord) to get the Lat/Lon values.

For example:

```
SELECT id, 
(3959 
    * acos(
        cos(radians(37)) 
        * cos(radians(Y(coord)))
        * cos(radians(X(coord)) - radians(-122)) 
        + sin(radians(37))
        * sin(radians(Y(coord)))
      )
) AS distance 
FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: 37 is lat and -122 is lon? And 25 is meters or km?

Answer (score 2):

Find the 100 restaurants nearest to some coordinate:  See efficient code in
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng
It includes a stored function for computing "great cirle" distance.

Better discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql This lists 5 ways, including the above one.